# Large RAM sticks on older motherboard - worry over making a BIOS RAM speed change

Tags: memory, bios

I have an ASUS motherboard from 2011 running Windows 7. It has 2 x 2GB of 1333 DDR3 RAM in its two slots for them.

I bought a Crucial 8 GB 1333 DDR3 UDIMM RAM stick. When I swapped the old RAM out and put the new RAM in, the motherboard menu screen shows for a second or two, the computer seems to power off and on, the same screen shows, over and over. I press keys like DEL but they have no effect. I tried both slots, same result.

With the old RAM in place I looked at the BIOS | chipset | RAM speed. It is set to Auto. When the computer runs, the RAM runs at 1333.

To solve our problem, I thought about trying a change of the BIOS speed from Auto to 1333 and testing the 8 GB stick. MY WORRY IS THIS: might the problem still be there, AND when I put the 2 x 2GB sticks back in place, will I be able to access the BIOS and then boot Windows?

Comment: wrong BIOS settings *probably won't* prevent you from accessing the BIOS, wrong hardware will. Is your motherboard compatible with the larger RAM sticks?

Comment: "will I be able to access the BIOS and then boot Windows?" - Impossible for us to say one way or another, but given the option is **already** switching between the two options, it's likely the option will likely reset when the hardware rediscovers different modules have been installed. If it does not boot performing a CMOS reset would likely resolve the issue. I would argue that changing it from auto to a specific speed likely won't solve your issue if the problem is due to an incompatibility due to the size of the module.

Comment: Motherboard Model/Revision would help (will be printed on the motherboard somewhere). And the full and exact names printed on all memory modules... otherwise my best guess at this stage would be a voltage incompatability. Look up and understand the DDR3 L and U variants - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#DDR3L_and_DDR3U_extensions

Comment: Thanks. I changed the RAM speed from Auto to 1333, but the outcome was the same.
The new RAM is Crucial 8 GB 1333 DDR3 UDIMM 1.35V CL9, part number  CT102464BA1339.C16FE.
It looks as though it is not compatible with the ASUS P7H55-M LX motherboard. Websites say the board can go up to 8 GB RAM. I guess it must be 4 GB in each of the two slots, not 8 GB in one slot.